# Replace characters and extract substrings from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have following pandas dataframe. I would like to replace some characters and extract substrings (there exists more rows in the original dataframe).

I am using following regex but I am unable to replace '?' from some rows like row 6, 7, 8.

```
df[['label', 'id']] = df['name'].str.extract(r'\{?\??\|?[[{]?(.*?)[]}]?(?:,\s+(\d{3,100}))?\s+\(\d+\)')
```

```
You-Hoover-Fong syndrome, 616954 (3)
Yuan-Harel-Lupski syndrome (4)
Zaki syndrome, 619648 (3)
Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 2, 616455 (3)
Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 3, 618658 (3)
[?Birbeck granule deficiency], 613393 (3)
[?Homosexuality, male] (2)
[?Phosphohydroxylysinuria], 615011 (3)
[Acetylation, slow], 243400 (3)
```

The expected output is:

```
You-Hoover-Fong syndrome          616954  
Yuan-Harel-Lupski syndrome
Zaki syndrome                     619648
Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 2      616455 
Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 3      618658 
Birbeck granule deficiency        613393 
Homosexuality, male 
Phosphohydroxylysinuria           615011 
Acetylation, slow                 243400
```

How can I modify the current regex to include the '?' to remove from the mentioned rows?

Comment: What's the code?

Comment: What is your current output? Do have to extract the desired substrings? It might be easier and presumably more readable to replace/remove the unwanted parts. Do the data originate from a single data source? Assuming each source has a consistent formatting, it might be easier to equalize data from each source before merging the datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df['number'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'(\d{6})').fillna('')
df['text'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'^[^a-zA-Z]*(.*?(?:\s*(?<!\()\d{,2}))[^a-zA-Z]*$')
df['text'] = df['text'].str.strip()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                           text  number
0      You-Hoover-Fong syndrome  616954
1    Yuan-Harel-Lupski syndrome        
2                 Zaki syndrome  619648
3  Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 2  616455
4  Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 3  618658
5    Birbeck granule deficiency  613393
6           Homosexuality, male        
7       Phosphohydroxylysinuria  615011
8             Acetylation, slow  243400
```

---

Initial dataframe:

```
                                        text
0       You-Hoover-Fong syndrome, 616954 (3)
1             Yuan-Harel-Lupski syndrome (4)
2                  Zaki syndrome, 619648 (3)
3   Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 2, 616455 (3)
4   Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 3, 618658 (3)
5  [?Birbeck granule deficiency], 613393 (3)
6                 [?Homosexuality, male] (2)
7     [?Phosphohydroxylysinuria], 615011 (3)
8            [Acetylation, slow], 243400 (3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just change the first part of your regex to match any number of `[`, `{`, `|` or `?` characters:

```
[[{?|]*(.*?)[]}]?(?:,\s+(\d{3,100}))?\s+\(\d+\)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GgfBAj/1)

In python

```py
df[['label', 'id']] = df['name'].str.extract(r'[[{?|]*(.*?)[]}]?(?:,\s+(\d{3,100}))?\s+\(\d+\)').fillna('')
```

Output:

```
                                        name                         label      id
0       You-Hoover-Fong syndrome, 616954 (3)      You-Hoover-Fong syndrome  616954
1             Yuan-Harel-Lupski syndrome (4)    Yuan-Harel-Lupski syndrome
2                  Zaki syndrome, 619648 (3)                 Zaki syndrome  619648
3   Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 2, 616455 (3)  Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 2  616455
4   Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 3, 618658 (3)  Zimmermann-Laband syndrome 3  618658
5  [?Birbeck granule deficiency], 613393 (3)    Birbeck granule deficiency  613393
6                 [?Homosexuality, male] (2)           Homosexuality, male
7     [?Phosphohydroxylysinuria], 615011 (3)       Phosphohydroxylysinuria  615011
8            [Acetylation, slow], 243400 (3)             Acetylation, slow  243400
```